# Subprococess calling a python script in Django running a server through Apache in Linux - Raspbian.

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, raspbian

I am working on a home automation project, and I want to run certain python codes when going to certain URLs of my Django Webpage. The subprocess.call() line from my Django Views.py works perfectly on my Django development server:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import subprocess

def home():
    subprocess.call(['python','path_to_python_file/python_file.py'])
    html = "<html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>" 
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

But the python script (or whatsoever command line) is not called on my Raspberry with Apache. According to many previous questions I've read, this could either be a SELinux issue or an premission issue. But I have given persmission to all users, groups, andd others to my python file:

```
sudo chmod a=rwx python_file.py
```

And still the python file is not executed. Using `subprocess.Popen`instead of `subprocess.call` does not work, and neither does setting `shell = True`.

Anyone has any idea of what I am missing here? Otherwise I'll try to switch over to CGI and drop subprocessing for running scripts :-)

Comment: you could try `subprocess.check_output` to see what's going on. the script is probably called, setting execution rights doesn't help since it's an argument of `python`, it's just that it fails silently

Comment: did you use subprocess.Popen & shell = True ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I did it and got "CalledProcessError at /

Command '['python', ''path_to_python_file/python_file.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Comment: see: the command _was_ called. It just failed for some reason. now you could use `Popen` and `communicate` to get the standard error output of the command.

Comment: Why are you running another Python script via subprocess anyway? Why don't you just import it and call the functions directly?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have essayé to `a = subprocess.Popen(['python','path_to_python_file/python_file.py'], , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`and `a.communicate()`. But nothing new is happening at the website a part from the "Hello World".  And if I  `print(a.communicate()`, the I can't see it on the website nor in the Shell.

Comment: in that case, just write it into a file where you have access to

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, when in my views I add `open("path to file/text_file.txt", "w")` I get a permission error! Permission denied to  `"path to file/text_file.txt"`. That is in opposition with `open("path to file/text_file.txt", "r")` for which no permission error is raised.

Comment: write in a directory where everyone has access.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not easy for me to find a folder where both apache group (www-data) and the Pi group have access....